Geckodriver Fails to Decode Response from Marionette after Deploying API
i'm using geckodriver in my api.
in my dockerfile i made this Snippet:
# Install geckodriver version 0.35.0
RUN wget -q https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.35.0/geckodriver-v0.35.0-linux64.tar.gz \
    && tar -xzf geckodriver-v0.35.0-linux64.tar.gz \
    && chmod +x geckodriver \
    && mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/ \
    && rm geckodriver-v0.35.0-linux64.tar.gz

yes i did the same thing with firefox and everything else.
when i made my docker image and run the container, everything works fine and even when i send the request it returns a 200 state(ok) and the response that i want.
well, since everything works fine for me, i deployed my api using render, and it gives me this error ;
==> Starting service...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/uvicorn", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 410, in main
    run(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 577, in run
    server.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 65, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1517, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 69, in serve
    await self._serve(sockets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 76, in _serve
    config.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 434, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 19, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    video_downloader = VideoDownloader()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/app.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service=Service('/usr/local/bin/geckodriver'))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 71, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 299, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to decode response from marionette
==> Exited with status 1
==> Common ways to troubleshoot your deploy: https://docs.render.com/troubleshooting-deploys
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/uvicorn", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 410, in main
    run(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 577, in run
    server.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 65, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1517, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 69, in serve
    await self._serve(sockets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 76, in _serve
    config.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 434, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 19, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    video_downloader = VideoDownloader()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/app.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service=Service('/usr/local/bin/geckodriver'))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 71, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 299, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to decode response from marionette
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/uvicorn", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 410, in main
    run(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 577, in run
    server.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 65, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1517, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 69, in serve
    await self._serve(sockets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 76, in _serve
    config.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 434, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 19, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    video_downloader = VideoDownloader()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/app.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service=Service('/usr/local/bin/geckodriver'))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 71, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 299, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to decode response from marionette


i tried to deploy it in Back4app and the same thing
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to decode response from marionette
i did some digging to see if the 'marionette' thing is important, and it was.
i, no joking, spent 4 days to find the solution, and i lost hope, so i'm here to see if someone did in fact got the same error and found solution
here's the code block where i'm calling selenium

        options = FirefoxOptions()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/firefox"
        options.set_preference('dom.ipc.processCount', 1)
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service=Service('/usr/local/bin/geckodriver'))

this the request:
{
    "data": {
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vueyx9TBEqE&pp=ygUOMC4zMCBzZWMgdmlkZW8%3D",
        "type": "mp3"
    }
}

what i expected is a binary response.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Well, I didn't solve the problem, and while I don't recall the exact nature of the problem anymore, I remember that my solution involved removing Selenium from the project and migrating my API from Render to Railway. After these changes, everything functioned correctly. I suspect the core issue was related to an unstable IP address associated with a specific port on the previous hosting service (Render).
